# Unable to find div when using ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

If I try and select a DOM element that exists within an ngIf directive, that element is null.  If I remove the ngIf, then I can select it.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  const outer = document.getElementById('external-events');
  console.log(outer);
}
```

Code inside a component template, div not found:

```
<div *ngIf="groupedPatchGroups">
  <div id="external-events">
      stuff here
  </div>
  <br />
</div>
```

Take away the *ngIf and outer reports the contents of the div.

Is ngAfterViewInit run before the data comes back to determine what happens with the ngIf?  I would expect the ngIf to run first and ngAfterViewInit to be the very last thing to run.

Note:  groupedPatchGroups value is set in the ngOnInit.

Comment: So is `groupedPatchGroups` loaded asynchronously? If so, then there's no guarantee it'll be loaded by the time `ngAfterViewInit` is run

Answer (score 1):

One way to access the newly created element is to set a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) on the `div`:

```
<div *ngIf="groupedPatchGroups">
  <div #externalEvents>
      stuff here
  </div>
  <br />
</div>
```

and to subscribe to the `QueryList.changes` event in `ngAfterViewInit`. You can also check if the element is already present in the DOM before subscribing.

```
@ViewChildren("externalEvents") externalEvents: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log("Before changes", this.externalEvents.first); // Maybe already present
  this.externalEvents.changes.subscribe((elements) => {
    // Do something with elements or with this.externalEvents
    let element = this.externalEvents.first;
    console.log("Changes detected", element);
    ...
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cigmkt) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

DOM element is only created with ngIf when the expression in ngIf is true,if expression in ngIf is false DOM element will not get created.In your case also if groupedPatchGroups= true then only you will get div that is inside ngIf div .

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
constructor(private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef)

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.cdref.detectChanges();
  const outer = document.getElementById('external-events');
  console.log(outer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this ngClass to your div, this will get your job done.

```
[ngClass]="{ 'd-none': condition}"
```

d-none is a css class to hide ass this to your styles file, it will hide the div is the condition is matched.

```
.d-none{ display: none; }
```